# How and when does the regeneration of cells that have died start?

Tags: cell-biology, death, cell-division

I assume that the replacement of cells that have died (or been removed by any means) doesn't work on a single cell level but starts only when some critical number of cells have died.

My question is: How is this signaled (to the regenerating cells), and how is the critical number encoded, i.e. the signal threshold at which regeneration starts?

Comment: Whatever the answers may be, keep in mind this is a broad question and an answer will not apply to all tissues. Take an epithelium such as the gut lining or the dermis. It may help for you to think rather in a dynamic way ("stem cells in the [crypt](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8e/Epithelial_cell_migration.tif/lossless-page1-220px-Epithelial_cell_migration.tif.png) respond to cues to speed up or slow down the rate of cell replenishment") as opposed to a static way ("of 10 cells, 2 die; this crosses the repair threshold, so 2 cells divide to restore cell count of 10").

Comment: @SPr: Thanks for the enlightening comment and the instructive picture you point me to - I wasn't aware of "stem cells in the crypt" (what a great name by the way!) Nevertheless: **What are those cues the stem cells respond to?**

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but it is known that stem cells proliferate in response to a variety of [mechanical](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0124529), [biological](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-09010-6), and [chemical](https://dev.biologists.org/content/135/9/1575) cues/signals. They may respond to signals released by compromised cells, to wound healing cues from platelets for instance, to apoptotic bodies, to stretching or exposure to the atmosphere, to paracrine, immune or endocrine signaling, etc. And it's quite tissue specific. Hope that helps.